# Image adjustment in CSS

Tags: html, css

eed some help with the css for an image.

This is the HTML

```
    <div class="main">
    <div class="loginform">
        <h1 align="left">'Welcome to .'</h1>   
        <p align="left">'Supporting our customers by providing documentation for all products across the Suite.'</p>
    </div>      

    <div class ="background"></div>
    </div>
```

This is the latest css

```
     .main {
     widht: 400px;
     height:100px;
     }

    .background
    {
     background-   
     image:url("icon.png?la=en&h=270&w=320");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position:right;  
     position:relative;
     opacity: 0.6;
     filter: alpha(opacity=60);
     height:300px;
     width:300px;
     z-index:1; 
     top:-105px;
     left:78%;
     clear:both;
     }
```

My image is looking something like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I would love to have it like this. The green image should not be visible in the password box.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: please give your css

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, the picture has to be a background image of loginform for example. [Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/aivaraspauga/dy1o3evr/)

```
.loginform {  
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('http://www.itsmfonline.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/accenture_high_performance.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: right center; 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not getting the exact result. Let me play around with the values and check.

Comment: Hi Aivaras, can you please check the third image I have attached above.

Comment: Like @Anubhav said it would be very helpful if we could see Your full CSS

Comment: Hi Aivaras, the full css is mentioned above. Thanks again for looking and helping em with this issue. It is the one which starts with (.main)

Comment: Check out this fiddle it should clear things up https://jsfiddle.net/aivaraspauga/urtbvkr2/

Comment: Hi Aivaras...i tried your options but for some reasons it giving me the output as mentioned above. I have modified the question with the latest css. Can you please check? Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by position the image relatively towards the `main` div.
In that case you should work with z-index. See example: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fv1meg2L/1/)

I created my own HTML code. You should apply these CSS settings to your own code.

```
<div class="main">
<h1>
Welcome To
</h1>
<p>
Supporting our customers
</p>

<form>    
  <div class="left">
    Username<br/><input type="text" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Password <br/><input type="text" name="password">
  </div>  
  <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
<div class="background"></div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color:#fff;
}
form{
  cleaR:both;  
  position:relative; /* To set the Form above the bg image */
  z-index:3; /* To set the Form above the bg image */
  background-color:yellow;
}
.left, .right{
  width:48%;
  margin-left:1%;
  margin-right:1%;  
  float:left;  
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.left input, .right input{
   width:100%;
}
.background{
  background-image:url("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/arrow-25-xxl.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:right;    
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative; /* To set the bg behinde the form */
  z-index:1; /* To set the bg behinde the form */
  top:-120px; /* Set the position of the BG image */
  left:79%; /* Set the position of the BG image */
  background-color:green;
}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Comment: @PankajMorajkar I really do not get what you want. You just want to have the image behind the password box right?

Comment: Hi Rotan...Thanks for helping me with this issue....Yes i want it behind the box as shown in figure 2. I tried a lot of options but still didnt get it...

Comment: Hi Rotan... I have modified the question with the latest css. Can you please check? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @PankajMorajkar can you perhaps paste a link to your website? Because I can not fix any problems if I do not can simulate your design setting. Try to create a [JSFIDDLE](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of your code. That will make live much easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code https://jsfiddle.net/gdqkjade/

**Test CSS**

```
.main {
    widht: 400px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .input_fields{margin-top: 100px;}
  .background {
    background-image: url("https://www.accenture.com/t20160121T034706__w__/us-en/_acnmedia/Accenture/Conversion-Assets/DotCom/Images/Global/Technology_19/Accenture-T1-Green-Forward-Mark-icon.png?la=en&h=270&w=320");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;    
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: -1;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -15px;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
input{width: 90%;}
```

**Test HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="loginform">
    <h1 align="left">'Welcome to ALIP Documentation Center.'</h1>
    <p align="left">'Supporting our customers by providing documentation for all products across the Suite.'</p>

    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="input_fields">
      Username
      <br/>
      <input type="text" name="username">
    </div>
    <div>
      Password
      <br/>
      <input type="text" name="password">
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Aldrien...when i try your code the image goes completely behind the box. It seems your code is correct. The site on which I am trying this has container with the username and password box. I think i have to target the container.

Comment: What should i target ...for example if the container is "mt-content-container" what css can i put to achieve my objective?

Comment: Sorry not sure if it is the correct question also but just looking for guidance.

Comment: i think you need to change the class "input_fields" to "mt-content-container", and modify the "margin-top" value for right result.